# Insert data into MongoDB into custom collections based on input using node.js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, collections

I want to insert the document into MongoDB collection based on the input.
For eg if `nid = 1`, then i want to insert the document into collection `'One'`, if `nid = 2` then I want to insert the document into collection `'Two'` and so on.

The schema that i would use

```
{
    nid: Number,
    name: String
}
```

I have tried to initialize the schema in node.js with the collection name defined as a variable that has value based on the input.

```
var collVar = 'One';

var newSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nid: Number,
    name: String
},{collection: collVar});
```

However, the schema cannot be defined every time there is new new data to be inserted into MongoDB. 
Is there a way to insert data into different collections based on the input data entered without defining new schemas?

Comment: The one way that i found out was to create a new model from the defined schema for each insert with the collection name taken from the input and added to the model create statement. Like 
    var collName = 'One'
    var newModelSchema = mongoose.model('newModelSchema', collName, newSchema); 
   Just wanted to know a better solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can save nid as number and use a getter (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/getters-setters.html) to transform it to string.

example

```
const newSchema = new Schema({
  nid: {
    type: Number,
    get: toComprehensiveString
  }
});

function toComprehensiveString(nid) {
 if (nid === 1) {
   return 'One';
 }
 // or use a library / map here
}
```

I think it's the best way

Comment: That only stores 'One' into MongoDB when nid = 1. I however want to store nid = 1 into MongoDB but store it into collection named 'One' in the database. Another case if nid = 2, then i would want to store nid as 2 into the database but store it in a collection named 'Two'. I will have 9 predefined collections from 'One' to 'Nine' for which I could use the getter function you described. But my other concern is how do I store the data to the custom collection based on the value of nid field.